# One menu item to toggle between two states in WatchKit Context Menu

Tags: watchkit, watchos

I'm setting up a `Menu` and `Menu Item`s in Storyboard, and want one menu item to toggle between two states e.g. on/off, Celcius/Fahrenheit, etc.

However, control-dragging from a menu item to the interface controller doesn't let me create an outlet, but only has option to create an action. So although I can set up an action to toggle between two states, I'm not being able to change its `title` and `image` to show the current button state.

Is there a way to implement this correctly in WatchKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it this way - whenever you want to toggle your state - clear menu items:

`[self clearAllMenuItems];`

and then set up new menu items:

`[self addMenuItemWithImageNamed:@"myImage" title:@"action title" action:@selector(actionMethod)];`

Comment: `[self clearAllMenuItems];` will only clear menu items that were programmatically added; storyboard-added ones will still remain.